# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning won't animate frame size

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to animate transitioning between `UIViewControllers` with Pop-in effect.

In my `animateTransition(using transitionContext:)` function:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    if let toController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) {
        let toView = toController.view!

        let finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toController) // (20, 20, 200, 200)
        containerView.addSubview(toView)

        toView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: self.duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            toView.frame = finalFrame
        }, completion: {(completed: Bool) -> Void in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(completed)
        })
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the size of the frame would change from `100 by 100` to `200 by 200`. But it did not.

I found out that this function can animate the **position** of the frame while transitioning but not the **size**(width or height). How can I animate the size of the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to fact that probably you are using auto layout in your app.
Once the layout engine starts it reposition the view based on your original constraints.
Try to modify your constraints (or apply a transform), not the frame. Using auto layout modifying the frame is almost useless.

Comment: Haven't tried yet but I guess you're right that auto layout is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead of changing setting new frame with new size

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: self.duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        }, completion: {(completed: Bool) -> Void in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(completed)
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion but I need to maintain scale factors in the real project.